# How to implement double elimination algorithm in php?

Tags: php, tournament, double-elimination

Hereby I have attached some code snippets, which I had implemented but it is still not working.....

> competitors are representing the names of teams that are participating
>   in the competition. 
>   events are giving us the final result. 
>   rounds is basically used as a variable which differentiate the cases for number of teams

```
$competitors = array(
    "Louisville",
    "Duke",
    "Gonzaga",
    "Kansas",
    "Indiana",
    "Ohio State"
);

$rounds = log( count( $competitors ), 2 ) + 1;

// round one
for( $i = 0; $i < log( count( $competitors ), 2 ); $i++ )
{
    $seeded = array( );
    foreach( $competitors as $competitor )
    {
        $splice = pow( 2, $i );

        $seeded = array_merge( $seeded, array_splice( $competitors, 0, $splice ) );
        $seeded = array_merge( $seeded, array_splice( $competitors, -$splice ) );
    }
    $competitors = $seeded;
}
$events = array_chunk( $seeded, 2 );


if( $rounds > 2 )
{
    $round_index = count( $events );

    // second round
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $competitors ) / 2; $i++ )
    {
        array_push( $events, array(
            array( 'from_event_index' => $i, 'from_event_rank' => 1 ), // rank 1 = winner
            array( 'from_event_index' => ++$i, 'from_event_rank' => 1 )
        ) );
    }

    $round_matchups = array( );
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $competitors ) / 2; $i++ )
    {
        array_push( $round_matchups, array(
            array( 'from_event_index' => $i, 'from_event_rank' => 2 ), // rank 2 = loser
            array( 'from_event_index' => ++$i, 'from_event_rank' => 2 )
        ) );
    }
    $events = array_merge( $events, $round_matchups );

    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $round_matchups ); $i++ )
    {
        array_push( $events, array(
            array( 'from_event_index' => $i + count( $competitors ) / 2, 'from_event_rank' => 2 ),
            array( 'from_event_index' => $i + count( $competitors ) / 2 + count( $competitors ) / 2 / 2, 'from_event_rank' => 1 )
        ) );
    }
}

if( $rounds > 3 )
{
    // subsequent rounds
    for( $i = 0; $i < $rounds - 3; $i++ )
    {
        $round_events = pow( 2, $rounds - 3 - $i );
        $total_events = count( $events );

        for( $j = 0; $j < $round_events; $j++ )
        {
            array_push( $events, array(
                array( 'from_event_index' => $j + $round_index, 'from_event_rank' => 1 ),
                array( 'from_event_index' => ++$j + $round_index, 'from_event_rank' => 1 )
            ) );
        }

        for( $j = 0; $j < $round_events; $j++ )
        {
            array_push( $events, array(
                array( 'from_event_index' => $j + $round_index + $round_events * 2, 'from_event_rank' => 1 ),
                array( 'from_event_index' => ++$j + $round_index + $round_events * 2, 'from_event_rank' => 1 )
            ) );
        }

        for( $j = 0; $j < $round_events / 2; $j++ )
        {
            array_push( $events, array(
                array( 'from_event_index' => $j + $total_events, 'from_event_rank' => 2 ),
                array( 'from_event_index' => $j + $total_events + $round_events / 2, 'from_event_rank' => 1 )
            ) );
        }

        $round_index = $total_events;
    }

}

if( $rounds > 1 )
{
    // finals
    array_push( $events, array(
        array( 'from_event_index' => count( $events ) - 3, 'from_event_rank' => 1 ),
        array( 'from_event_index' => count( $events ) - 1, 'from_event_rank' => 1 )
     ) );
}
```

---

```
The problem I am facing in this:

 - No of cases I am getting are higher than actual. Like for n matches I obtain (2n-1) matches
 - In some cases there are decimal values which appear to be invalid data
 - Using this algorithm, I need to generate a bracket
```